# Program hangs up when using NAudio record sound and save

Tags: c#, naudio

I encountered some problems in using NAudio to save sound recordings. Most of time, the following code will work. It will start recording and saving to .wav file after I press the "start recording" button, and stops recording after I press the "stop" button. But sometimes, the program just hangs up after I click the recording button. I have to wait around 30 seconds before it starts recording properly.

```
    private WaveIn waveSource = null;
    private WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

    private void recordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recordButton.Enabled = false;
        stopRecordButton.Enabled = true;
        waveSource = new WaveIn();
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
        waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
        waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSouce_RecordingStopped);

        waveFile = new WaveFileWriter("test.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);
        waveSource.StartRecording();
    }

    private void stopRecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopRecordButton.Enabled = false;
        waveSource.StopRecording();
    }     

    private void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
        }
    }

    private void waveSouce_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisposeWave();
    }

    private void DisposeWave()
    {
        if (waveSource != null)
        {
            waveSource.Dispose();
            waveSource = null;
        }
        if (waveFile != null)
        {
            waveFile.Dispose();
            waveFile = null;
        }
    }
```

I set a break in visual studio, and found it hangs on line: waveSource.StartRecording(); 
It takes around 30 seconds to step into function: private void waveSource_DataAvailable().

I also ran this program on another computer, but I get the following exception text after I click the "start recording" button. I checked the Device Manager on that computer, and I'm pretty sure the sound card is properly installed.

```
************** Exception Text **************
NAudio.MmException: BadDeviceId calling waveInOpen
  at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.OpenWaveInDevice()
  at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.StartRecording()
  at ToeflSpeaking.MainForm.StartRecordingState() in c:\MyProgram\Toefl Speaking\code\MainForm.cs:line 268
  at ToeflSpeaking.MainForm.timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\MyProgram\Toefl Speaking\code\MainForm.cs:line 407
  at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: code looks ok. what have you tried to troubleshoot? Does this happen on more than one computer. When it hangs, can you break in visual studio and see what line of code it's on?

Comment: Hi Mark. I didn't have a chance to try this on another computer, but I set a break in visual studio, and found it hangs in line: waveSource.StartRecording(). It takes around 30 seconds to step into waveSource_DataAvailable.

Comment: what sort of application is this? Windows Forms, WPF?

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application.

Comment: WaveInAudio works inappropriate under WinForms control. It is not fault of NAUDIO, it is CLR fault.. It destroys the incoming data thread in unmanaged area.
Use ConsoleApplication/